# Tail recursion when loading lot of items

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift, reactive

I need to load a lot of small files from an api that allows me to load only one file at a time. As they are very small I start several downloads at a time. Depending on the result I start the next batch load.

For each request I use a observable and then combine several with `combineLatest`. After `combineLatest` I do a `flatMap` and `concat` a new call to the same function.

As abstraction I do this - *pseudo code, not compiling*:

```
func loadRecursively(items) -> Observable<XY> {
    combineLatest(requestObservables)
    .flatMap {
        return loadRecursively(items-loadedItems)
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in general.

**The problem:** This leads to a growing recursive tail, which is not cut off by compiler optimisation as it seems. So when loading some thousand files the stack will grow and finally the app will close.

How would I avoid the growing tail? Or in general how would I approach this problem with rx?

Comment: Hi, @beseder. Did my answer help you? Or you solve your problem in different way?

Answer (score 1):

`RxSwift` has `concatMap` operator (because people had been faced with [same problem](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1093)), that allows you to sequentially loop through your `Observable`s.

Simple example:

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .concatMap(Observable.just)
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
4
```